# QtNeworkReply runs forever and never finishes

Tags: qt

I'm trying to write a very simple client for a Rest API that I'm developing.

All I want to do is send a request (no parameters, not data) to my only endpoint and print out the data that is sent back.

So here is my code

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString address = "http://localhost/test_api/welcome.php";

    QUrl api_url = QUrl(address);

    qDebug() << "Sending the request";
    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
        //connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    QNetworkReply *reply = networkManager->post(QNetworkRequest(api_url),QByteArray());

    while (!reply->isFinished()){
        if (!reply->isRunning()){
            break;
        }
    }

    qDebug() << "Reply is finished";

    if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError){
        qDebug() << "The following error ocurred";
        qDebug() << reply->errorString();
        return 0;
    }

    QString data_returned(reply->readAll());

    qDebug() << "DATA RETURNED";
    qDebug() << data_returned;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, it hangs because reply is never finshed and is always running.

Do I need to create a class just for receiving the finished signal from the QtNeworkManager or is there something else wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible problem is that the while loop is blocking the execution of the request that is asynchronous. One possible solution is to use QEventLoop:

```cpp
QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
QNetworkReply *reply = networkManager->post(QNetworkRequest(api_url),QByteArray());

QEventLoop loop;
QObject::conect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
loop.exec();

qDebug() << "Reply is finished";
```

Comment: Thank you!! This was the issue!!